# How to use RabbitMQ with iOS and Swift

Tags: swift, rabbitmq

I want to use RabbitMQ to communicate with a server using Swift on an iOS device, but I'm encountering errors. Can you explain or show me the source code?

My code:

```
import RMQClient

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // 서버로부터 로그를 받아오기 위한 함수 호출
        self.emitLog()
        self.receiveLogs()
        
        // 원하는 시점에 메시지 보내기 (예: 버튼 클릭 등)
       
    }
    
    func createConnection() -> RMQConnection {
        let hostName = "112.219.138.test" // 호스트명
        let userName = "test" // 유저 이름
        let password = "test" // 비밀번호
        let virtualHost = "/" // 가상 호스트 (기본값인 "/"를 사용하려면 변경하지 마세요)

        let uri = "amqp://\(userName):\(password)@\(hostName):5672\(virtualHost)"
        let delegate = RMQConnectionDelegateLogger()
        let connection = RMQConnection(uri: uri, delegate: delegate)
        return connection
    }
    
    func emitLog() {
        let conn = createConnection()
        conn.start()
        let ch = conn.createChannel()
        let x = ch.fanout("logs")
        let msg = "Hello, RabbitMQ!" // 보낼 메시지 내용을 설정하세요
        x.publish(msg.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!) // 메시지를 발행
        print("Sent \(msg)")
        conn.close()
    }

    
    func receiveLogs() {
        let conn = createConnection()
        conn.start()
        let ch = conn.createChannel()
        let x = ch.fanout("logs")
        let q = ch.queue("", options: .exclusive)
        q.bind(x)
        print("Waiting for logs...")
        q.subscribe({ (_ message: RMQMessage) -> Void in
            if let messageString = String(data: message.body, encoding: .utf8) {
                // 받은 로그를 출력
                print("Received Log: \(messageString)")
                
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This tutorial emits this:

```
Sent Hello, RabbitMQ!
Received connection: <RMQConnection: 0x60000301c090> failedToConnectWithError: Error Domain=com.rabbitmq.rabbitmq-objc-client Code=1 "attempt to close an already closed (or never successfully established) connection" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=attempt to close an already closed (or never successfully established) connection}
Waiting for logs...
Thread Performance Checker: Thread running at User-initiated quality-of-service class waiting on a lower QoS thread running at Background quality-of-service class. Investigate ways to avoid priority inversions
PID: 27587, TID: 8236637
Backtrace

=================================================================

3   RMQClient                           0x0000000101d816cc -[RMQSemaphoreWaiter timesOut] + 92
4   RMQClient                           0x0000000101d3dd8c __23-[RMQConnection start:]_block_invoke + 604
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102433747 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001024349f7 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010243c8c9 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 1127
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010243d665 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 441
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010244a76e _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 318
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102449b69 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 590
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000101143c47 _pthread_wqthread + 327
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000101142b97 start_wqthread + 15

nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C2:1] Socket SO_ERROR [54: Connection reset by peer]
nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [54: Connection reset by peer]
Received connection: <RMQConnection: 0x600003014120> disconnectedWithError: Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "Socket closed by remote peer" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Socket closed by remote peer}
Will start recovery for connection: <RMQConnection: 0x600003014120>
Received connection: <RMQConnection: 0x60000301c090> disconnectedWithError: Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "Socket closed by remote peer" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Socket closed by remote peer}
Starting recovery for connection: <RMQConnection: 0x600003014120>
Recovered connection: <RMQConnection: 0x600003014120>
nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C3:1] Socket SO_ERROR [54: Connection reset by peer]
Received connection: <RMQConnection: 0x600003014120> disconnectedWithError: Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "Socket closed by remote peer" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Socket closed by remote peer}
```

Comment: start connection once and don't close...

Comment: there must be listener which says connection is done... in that call `receiveLogs`